# How to make a Java jar file and a SQLite db a single executable file?

Tags: java, sqlite, jar, exe, executable-jar

I developed a JAVAFX app that uses a SQLite database to stores data. When I export the jar of the app, it creates the db in the same dir of the jar file. To load db files inside a jar, I could use `jdbc:sqlite::resource:` prefix, but it's READ-ONLY. How I can wrap or convert the JAR file to make a single executable file with jar and db inside? Any solution is accepted to make one single executable file contained java program and db (.exe or .jar or something else)

Comment: If you create a jar with the .db file in it, you will not be able to edit it. It will only be possible, if you copy it somewhere and then edit. But the file inside the jar/exe cannot be edited.

Comment: If your problem is that the database is read-only, you should ask a question specifically about that. If you want to just use an SQLite database while your program is running, and don't care about persisting the changes, there are solutions to that as well. Try to make your question more specific and maybe someone will be able to answer.